# Programmatically split webfont to multiple unicode ranges

Tags: node.js, fonts, gruntjs

How can I split a woff2 file containing, say latin characters, cyrillic characters and chinese characters into 3 different files, preferably using nodejs/grunt?

Is there a way to automatically determine at which points the different sets begin and end?

I have tried [unicode-range-splitter](https://github.com/nazar-pc/unicode-range-splitter/blob/master/splitter.php) but it just splits my font into equally big chunks, which does not help me achieving my goal.

I also had a look at [grunt-webfont-svg-extractor](https://github.com/agallou/grunt-webfont-svg-extractor) in conjunction with [grunt-fonts](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont) but since these tools were not exactly built for this requirement the configs are awkwardly long and error-prone.

Comment: I'm quite certain you'll need to utilize unicode ranges (i.e. _from/to_), which are defined [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm), as a way to determine _begin_ and _end_ of sets/blocks. There's no explicit _begin_ and _end_ delimiter that I'm aware of. If your ultimate intent for splitting the fonts is to optimize browser load performance/times, then you could consider specifying the [unicode-range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range) in your `@font-face` rules instead of splitting the font into separate fonts.

Comment: @RobC, according to the MDN link you posted, _If the page doesn't use any character in this range, the font is not downloaded; if it uses at least one, the whole font is downloaded._. This means I will *have* to split the font in order to use this property effectively. Thanks for the definition table, I think I can work with that.

Comment: Yes you're correct Tom - thanks for rectifying my misunderstanding. With regards to tooling for splitting the font there is [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools) and the `pyftsubset` command (It's written in Python though!). Example usage of the `pyftsubset` command can be found in this [blog](https://michaeljherold.com/2016/05/04/creating-a-subset-font.html) - The `--unicodes` option is used to specify the unicode range. With regards to grunt integration, you can utilize [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to invoke the command - that's about it though.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you :) if you post an answer containing the unicode range table and an example fonttools command I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no explicit *begin* and *end* delimiter as such which marks each set of Latin, Cyrillic, and Chinese characters.

You can specify a unicode range (i.e. *from/to*), as a way to distinguish the *begin* and *end* of each set/block. For example, below are some pertinent ranges:

**Unicode ranges**

| Name | From | To |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Basic Latin | `U+0000` | `U+007F` |
| Cyrillic | `U+0400` | `U+04FF` |
| CJK Unified Ideographs | `U+4E00` | `U+9FFF` |
| ... |  |  |

A complete list of unicode blocks/ranges can be found listed [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm).

**Tools**

There's no specific grunt plugin, nor nodejs solution, to perform the font splitting that I'm aware of. However there is [fonttools](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools), which is written in Python, and includes a command named `pyftsubset`.

Below is an example of using the `pyftsubset` command *(taken from [this blog](https://michaeljherold.com/2015/05/04/creating-a-subset-font/) and slightly adapted)*:

```
$ pyftsubset My-Awesome-Font-Regular.ttf \
    --unicodes="U+0400-04FF" \
    --layout-features="" \
    --flavor="woff" \
    --output-file="My-Awesome-Font-Cyrillic.woff"
```

Note the `--unicodes` option in the command above - this is where you specify the range(s) of characters you want to include (i.e. subset).

The various options for the `pyftsubset` command and their descriptions can be found [here](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools/blob/1adf7fd2c09e62322eea9b6a1866e79952cda943/Lib/fontTools/subset/__init__.py#L47).

Answer (score 4):

Use **Font-Ranger**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-ranger

With `font-ranger` you can:

- Generate subsets for each language you support
- Remove bloat from your fonts and optimize them for web
- Convert your fonts to a compressed woff2 format
- Provide .woff fallback for older browsers
- Generate CSS files with @font-face rules
- Automate operations using Node.js API